# MediaPlayer setDataSource to expansionFilePath doesn't work

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I'm trying to load a movie from a file within a mounted Google Play APK expansion OBB file.

```
mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

StorageManager storageManager = (StorageManager)mParentActivity.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);

String obbPath = ExpansionHelper.getExpansionFilePath(mParentActivity);
File movie = new File(storageManager.getMountedObbPath(obbPath), filename);

Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Movie exists is " + movie.exists());

mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(obbPath);
```

Note: movie exists logs 'true'

> E/MediaPlayer(27155): Error (1,-2147483648) Error while opening the
>   file. Unloading the media player (Unspecified media player error,
>   -2147483648) E/MediaPlayer(27155): stop called in state 0 E/MediaPlayer(27155): error (-38, 0)

How can I play a movie from an APK OBB expansion file (not the zip kind)?

Comment: Got same issue on 2.3.x Android version but it is working well on more recent version. On which Android version did you faced this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure why this method does work but if you provide a FileDescriptor from FileInputStream is work like a charm!

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(movie);
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(fis.getFD());
fis.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, just seen this question regards non-zipped files, well here is zipped version anyway:

```
private static void setMediaPlayerDataSourceFromZip(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer,
        String zipFileName, String fileNameInZip) throws IOException,
        FileNotFoundException {
    ZipResourceFile zip = new ZipResourceFile(zipFileName);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(zipFileName);
    try {
        FileDescriptor zipfd = fis.getFD();

        ZipEntryRO entry = zipFindFile(zip, fileNameInZip);
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(zipfd, entry.mOffset,
                entry.mUncompressedLength);
    } finally {
        fis.close();
    }
}

private static ZipEntryRO zipFindFile(ZipResourceFile zip, String fileNameInZip) {
    for (ZipEntryRO entry : zip.getAllEntries()) {
        if (entry.mFileName.equals(fileNameInZip))
            return entry;
    }
    throw new RuntimeException(String.format("File \"%s\"not found in zip", fileNameInZip));
}
```

Usage:

```
setMediaPlayerDataSourceFromZip(mediaPlayer,
   "/Some/zip/obb/withoutCompression.zip",
   "path/within/zip/mymovie.mp4");
```